# How do I show the following two distributions are equivalent

Tags: probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

Given a distribution $\mathbf{P}$ over $\mathcal{R}^d$, we have the following two sets of random vectors:

$\mathcal{A} = \{\mathbf{X}\mid\mathbf{X} \sim \mathbf{P} \}$

$\mathcal{B} = \{\mathbf{Z}\mid \mathbf{Z} \sim \mathbf{P} \text{ subject to } \mathbf{Z}_0 = \mathbf{X}_0 \text{ where } \mathbf{X} \sim \mathbf{P}\}$, where we use subscript 0 denote the first element of the $d$-dimension vector.

We say that the underlying distribution of $\mathcal{A}$ (or $\mathcal{B}$) is $\mathbf{P}_\mathcal{A}$ (or $\mathbf{P}_\mathcal{B}$), and $\mathbf{P}_\mathcal{A} = \mathbf{P}$.

$\mathbf{P}_\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathbf{P}_\mathcal{B}$ are equivalent (I guess), but how can I show this formally?

Comment: There are a couple of things which seems unclear to me, namely the following.
1) If $\mathbf{P}$ is a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $X\sim \mathbf{P}$, then $X$ is not a random variable but a random vector 2) You do not mention the space on which your random vector/variables are defined, which may or may not be important 3) What do you mean by "underlying distribution"? I mean if every $X\in \mathcal{A}$ has distribution $\mathbf{P}$, then wouldn't the underlying distribution be $\mathbf{P}$?

Comment: Also, the condition in your definition of $\mathcal{B}$ is trivially satisfied with $X=Z$, so unless we are considering a fixed $X$ (which you should mention), then $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I edited a little bit, and my main confusion is whether I can just directly say $X=Z$ (there is a one-to-one correspondence between $X$ and $Z$) given the condition. If so, then I should have no problem of this question.

Comment: It really depends on how you condition should be read. Is it "For all $Z\in \mathcal{B}$ there exists a $X$ with $X\sim \mathbf{P}$, such that $Z_0=X_0$."? or is it meant to be read as "There exists a $X$ with $X\sim \mathbf{P}$, such that for all $Z\in \mathcal{B}$, $Z_0=X_0$."?

Comment: But i am still unsure of what you are actually asking. I mean if both $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ has underlying distribution $\mathbf{P}$, then what is there to show? Perhaps you are using som abstract definition of "underlying distribution", which i am not aware of?